# Editing a UITableView that contains dynamic data in each row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that is separated into sections with one row each. Each row contains a horizontally scrolled UICollectionView. I am wanting to add the functionality for editing this list when I tap a general edit button in the top of my Navigation Controller. The issue that I'm thinking of is that all of the content will still move around and be active (tapping on a cell in the CollectionView will open a different page). I am wanting the edit mode to either disable that functionality or slide all of the content over simultaneously and have an edit button next to them all. When this edit button is pressed it will take the user to an edit page specific to that rows content (so no delete functionality here). Another reason why I am having a difficult time is that all of the content in the table will be loaded via data so I don't want to reload any of it.

Bottom line is that I need to select a single row and it must be done via a button that slides in or altering the functionality of the content there to act as a button. I cannot reload the data in the rows, though because it is loaded via internet data.